# Does django 3.2 support mongodb?

Tags: django, pymongo

I found no folder at django package's database folder like other database folder such as like mysql,sqlite etc.

Comment: You can use `djongo`...

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem `djongo (1.3.4) depends on django (>=2.1,<=3.0.5)`, the question is about `django 3.2`